# how do I Display Author picture in Sharepoint Blog

Tags: blog

I'm looking to setup a blog site using web interface.
how do I Display Author picture in Sharepoint Blog. All the posts by users needs to be accompanied with their profile picture.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: @elorg version is 2010 server

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if its still actual, but if your users have a profile photo, you can go to the "Posts" list settings, choose column "Created by" and set "show field" to "Name (with picture)" or picture and details. It depends on way how you use profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a picture library and a list of authors then relate both through a lookup property.

Then on login, you run the logged in user into a query against their pictures. Thus when one is posting, the picture is attached by default along with the post.